# This question isn't a duplicate, and should not have been closed on that basis

Tags: discussion, status-completed, exact-duplicates

This question isn't a duplicate, and should not have been closed on that basis:

[Why exactly the vapor pressure decreases when a non-volatile solute is added to a pure solvent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139961/why-exactly-the-vapor-pressure-decreases-when-a-non-volatile-solute-is-added-to)

The OP is asking for a microscopic kinetic explanation.  The answers to the other question only provide thermodynamic explanations.  I don't know what the kinetic answer is, so I'd be interested to see someone answer it myself.

Comment: On one hand, the community did suggest the duplicate question; but on the other hand, the OP did also accept the suggested duplicate — that's why you see OP and Community♦ as two of the "closers" (this happens when OP agrees that the linked question answers their own). So, you might also want to prod the OP to reconsider that(?).

Comment: @orthocresol  What's the mechanism by which the OP asks to have it reopened?  Is there a particular button he clicks on?

Comment: I think OP can contribute one reopen vote themselves. You’d need additional reopen votes from the community to get it reopened. Of course, you don’t actually need the OP’s own vote to get it reopened. I just thought it would be a little odd not doing so, as it would sort of be going against OP’s wishes in a way, if you get what I mean...

Comment: @orthocresol  OK, I mentioned it to the OP.

Comment: @orthocresol - I'd liked how the community respects the decision of any person, and I'd tried the same, when many people suggested me the dupe. At that time, I haven't enough time to read the whole post, so I've just accepted it. But, after theorist's point, I would like it to be re-opened. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As per [OP's request in the comments](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4834/this-question-isnt-a-duplicate-and-should-not-have-been-closed-on-that-basis#comment10460_4834)

> [image]

the question [Why exactly the vapor pressure decreases when a non-volatile solute is added to a pure solvent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139961) has been re-opened.